# Validation fileds from ajax request [Laravel 5]

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my validation request :rules

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UpdateCommentRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        $user = Auth::user()->id;
        return [
            'comment' => 'required|between:15,600',
            'projectID' => "required|exists:project_group,project_id,user_id,$user|numeric",
            'order' => "required|numeric",
            'level' => "required|numeric"
        ];
    }

}
```

And in my model I have like this:

```
public function apiUpdateComment(UpdateCommentRequest $request){

    $comment = Comment::find(Input::get("order"));
    $comment->text = Input::get('comment');
    if($comment->save()){
        return 'success';
    }

 }
```

This fileds I need to validate agins rules array:

```
    array(
        'comment' => Input::get('comment'),
        'projectID' => Input::get('projectID'),
        'order' => Input::get("order"),
        'level' => Input::get("level"),
    );
```

I need to check if all rules are ok and then update comment... Anyone can help?

Comment: I don't understand the issue. If you're passing a Request object, the request will only pass if the rules() are passed. So the body the `apiUpdateComment` will only run if `UpdateCommentRequest->rules()` returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function apiUpdateComment(UpdateCommentRequest $request){
    $comment = Comment::find($request->get("order"));
    $comment->text = $request->get('comment');
    if($comment->save()){
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

The logic behind the code:
A post request is send the the server and the route file sends it the the `apiUpdateComment` with all variables inside the `$request`. But before the code of the function is executed the validator checks the rules in your `UpdateCommentRequest`. If the test fails it will return errors. If it pass a comment with the id will be updated.

Comment: Is this code validate all ajax fileds or just this: `$request->get("order")`, `$request->get('comment')` ? I need to validate all fileds and if validation pass to update this: `$comment->text`

Comment: The validation takes place in the `UpdateCommentRequest` class. `comment` is just the field being updated